# Why isn't $digest automatically being triggered when using $q

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I was under the impression that using Angular's built-in functions (like `$timeout`, `$q`, etc...) triggers `$digest` automatically. But it seems that it only works for services fully defined within Angular, but not for those defined outside of Angular, even though they use `$q` and exposed via a wrapper Service. **Why?**

Suppose I have 2 services that do the same thing:

**The first** is a normal JS service, which uses `$q`:

```
var NonAngularService = (function($q){

return {
   doStuff: {
       var d = $q.defer()
       // do async function, like setTimeout, and d.resolve()
       return d.promise;
   }
}

})(angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$q"));
```

which is then wrapped by an Angular Service so that it could be injected into controllers:

```
app.factory("NonAngularService", function(){
   return NonAngularService;
});
```

**The other** service does the same thing, but defined fully within the Angular Service:

```
app.factory("AngularService", function($q){
   return {
       doStuff: {
           var d = $q.defer()
           // do async function, like setTimeout, and d.resolve()
           return d.promise;
       }
    }
});
```

Only in the second case the $digest is called automatically:

```
NonAngularService.doStuff()
  .then(function(data) {
      $scope.data1 = data;
      $scope.$digest(); // required here
  });

AngularService.doStuff()
  .then(function(data) {
      $scope.data1 = data;
      // $scope.$digest(); // Not required here
  });
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MwE0FTXKqLjgduLq8mKw?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used angular.injector myself, but it definitely looks like the `$q` you get from it is not exactly the one passed by dynamic dependency injection from a directive. The difference between the two being one triggers a `$digest` when it is resolved, while the other will actually triggers its promise `then` call during the next digest cycle.

I've set up this little change in your code trying to understand (the difference being we pass the $q in parameter instead of getting it via angular.injector).

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGjfWUViz4iidvxd0hre?p=preview

This may come from a change in some version of angular when they decided `$q` should handle the digest cycle itself. I guess that would be interesting to discuss that directly with its developpers on github or google groups.

PS: my `getNonAngularService` actually becomes a service I agree, the point was more to prove the `$q` were different.

Comment: This seems to be correct (at least partially, if the injector injects the same `$q, but one without access to $scope). I tried the opposite case ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/23DVH0BixsvKey9sqKPL?p=preview)) where I inject into the "AngularService" without using the typical DI, and it does not call $digest.